# Getting a list of xml element from Descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This is my Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dati>
  <product id="456">
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
    <item>c</item>
  </product>
  <product id="789">
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
  </product>
  <product id="533">
    <item>a</item>
  </product>
</dati>
```

Code below returns only first item.InnerText element

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var q = from c in Doc.Descendants("product")
        where c.Attribute("id").Value == "789"
        select c.Element("item");

foreach (string name in q)
       lst.Add(name);

listBox1.DataSource = lst;
```

how can I have a collection of all items for selected product?

Comment: Wouldn't `c.Elements("item")` return all of the nodes under `<item>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure:

```
var list = Doc.Descendants("product")
              .Single(c => c.Attribute("id").Value == "789")
              .Elements("item")
              .Select(item => (string) item)
              .ToList();
```

Note that this takes a slightly different approach - it checks that there's exactly one matching product element (by finding it) and then selects the `item` elements underneath it, projecting each to its value. It then converts those strings into a list in a rather neater way :)

Comment: Thanks Jon! :) That's perfect!

Comment: The power of Lambda Expressions.. :-)

Comment: if "item" property has children properties, this way concatenates all of them respectively.

Comment: @nsarchar: Well, only in that that's what the `XElement` string conversion does... if you want different behaviour, change the `Select` call.